# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int64 in SQL query with IN keyword

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, long-integer

I have following table structures.

```
  **Table_A**
        A_Id(BigInt)    Category_Ids(varchar(50))
        1                        1,2,3
        2                         2,3

    **Table_B**
        B_Id(BigInt)    C_Id(Bigint)    Name(varchar(50))
        1                         2              A
        2                         1              C
        3                         3              B
```

**First Query:**
    In this query want to get the record where A_Id=1. I have executed following code.
    **Select [Category_Ids] from Table_A where A_Id=1**
    This returns the data table with single column and single row with values “1, 2, 3”
    Assume that above query fills the data into the A_datatable. I get the string from following code.
    String ids = A_datatable.column[0][“Category_Ids”];

**Second Query:**
Now, I have to fetch the values from Table_B where C_Id in (1, 2, 3). I have executed following code and passed the string value to following query.
**Select * from Table_B where C_Id in (ids)**
When I execute above query getting the error, **failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int64.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do it in a single query.

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    Table_A a
        INNER JOIN Table_B b
            ON ',' + a.Category_IDs + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(C_ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',%'
WHERE   a.A_ID = 1
```

Caveat: This query is an index-killer. You should have properly normalize your tables.

**UPDATE 1**

Suggested Schema Design,

Table_A

- A_ID
- Category_ID

Table_C

- B_ID
- C_ID
- Name

---

**Records**

Table_A

```
A_ID    Category_ID
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       4
2       5
```

Table_B

```
B_Id    C_Id    Name
1       2       A
2       1       C
3       3       B
```

Comment: [**Here's a demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c5b8/1). The demo is running on `MySQL` server because I can't create on `SQL Server`. The concatenation differs but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string splitter function like the one described here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

scroll down to the 'CREATE FUNCTION' script and run it to create your function, then you can split the comma separate string for use in your 'where in' clause

select * from Table_B
where C_Id in (select item  from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(IDS,','))